# Count consecutive numbers in a vector

Tags: r, vector

If I have a vector like

```
"a": 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

I want to know how many `1` are together in `a`, in this case the answer would be 3 and 2.

Is there any script that can do this?

Comment: I've seen at least 3 questions in 2 days of people searching for `rle` it's an obscure function but very handy.

Answer (score 21):

See `?rle`.

```
## create example vector
a <- c(rep(0, 3), rep(1, 3), rep(0, 4), rep(1, 2), rep(0, 3))

## count continuous values
r <- rle(a)

## fetch continuous length for value 1
r$lengths[r$values == 1]
# [1] 3 2
```

Comment: Isn't it `values` and not `value`? Partial matching with `$` finds the right info, but so would `rle(a)$v` to take it to an extreme.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
test <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)
rle(test)$lengths[rle(test)$values==1]
#[1] 3 2
```

For massive data, you can speed it up a bit using some convoluted selecting:

```
diff(unique(cumsum(test == 1)[test != 1]))
#[1] 3 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Others have answered the question. I would just like to add two observations:

Data entry trick: use scan (defaults to class "numeric", no need for rep's or comma's) and it also works for characters separated by whitespace if you add "character" as an argument.

```
a <- scan()
1: 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
16: 
Read 15 items
```

`rle` is really the inverse function for `rep`

```
 arle <- rle(a)
 rep(arle$values, arle$lengths)
 [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: I thought rle was the inverse function for inverse.rle ;)